# Problem with events in BLoC Flutter. I always call two events instead of one

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I return the state with the TodoLoadedState list in each block method. But when I call the block event in onPressed, the list itself is not returned and I have to add a second call to the block method todoBloc.add(LoadTodos()); But that's not correct. Ideas need to trigger 1 event but to perform 2 actions, the second action is to update the list. Thanks in advance!

**todo_bloc**

```
class TodoBloc extends Bloc<TodoEvent, TodoState> {
  final TodoRepository todoRepository;

  TodoBloc(this.todoRepository) : super(TodoEmptyState()) {
    on<LoadTodos>((event, emit) async {
      emit(TodoLoadingState());
      try {
        final List<Todo> _loadedTodoList = await todoRepository.getAllTodos();
        emit(TodoLoadedState(loadedUser: _loadedTodoList));
      } catch (_) {
        emit(TodoErrorState());
      }
    });
    on<CreateTodos>((event, emit) async {
      // Todo todo = Todo(description: event.task, isDone: false);
      await todoRepository.insertTodo(event.todo);
      final List<Todo> _loadedTodoList = await todoRepository.getAllTodos();
      emit(TodoLoadedState(loadedUser: _loadedTodoList));
    });
    on<DeleteTodos>((event, emit) async {
      await todoRepository.deleteTodo(event.id);
      final List<Todo> _loadedTodoList = await todoRepository.getAllTodos();
      emit(TodoLoadedState(loadedUser: _loadedTodoList));
    });
    on<UpdateTodos>((event, emit) async {
      await todoRepository.updateTodo(event.todo);
      final List<Todo> _loadedTodoList = await todoRepository.getAllTodos();
      emit(TodoLoadedState(loadedUser: _loadedTodoList));
    });
  }
}
```

**todo_list**

```
class TodoList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TodoBloc todoBloc = context.read<TodoBloc>();
    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is TodoEmptyState) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text(
            'No Todo',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        );
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadingState) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadedState) {
        return ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: state.loadedUser.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Column(children: [
                    Text('${state.loadedUser[index].description}'),
                    Text('${state.loadedUser[index].id}'),
                  ]),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      todoBloc.add(DeleteTodos(id: state.loadedUser[index].id));
                      todoBloc.add(LoadTodos());
                    },
```

**home_page**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final todoRepository = TodoRepository();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Todos'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TodoList(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add, size: 32, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () {
            final TodoBloc todoBloc = context.read<TodoBloc>();
            final _todoDescriptionFromController = TextEditingController();
            showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (builder) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Container(
```

**todo_state**

```
abstract class TodoState extends Equatable {
  const TodoState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class TodoLoadingState extends TodoState {}

class TodoEmptyState extends TodoState {}

class TodoLoadedState extends TodoState {
  List<dynamic> loadedUser;

  TodoLoadedState({required this.loadedUser});
}

class TodoErrorState extends TodoState {}
```

**todo_event**

```
abstract class TodoEvent extends Equatable {
  const TodoEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadTodos extends TodoEvent {}

class CreateTodos extends TodoEvent {
  final Todo todo;

  const CreateTodos(this.todo);
}

class UpdateTodos extends TodoEvent {
  final Todo todo;

  const UpdateTodos(this.todo);
}

class DeleteTodos extends TodoEvent {
  final int id;

  const DeleteTodos({required this.id});
}

class QueryTodo extends TodoEvent {}
```

**event onPressed, everywhere you have to use 2 events to load the updated list**

```
todoBloc.add(UpdateTodos(updateTodo));
todoBloc.add(LoadTodos());
```

Comment: What version of bloc are you using? Also could you include your `Todo` class in your question?

Comment: I use flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1. All related code added to the question. I will be grateful if you help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
abstract class TodoState extends Equatable {
  const TodoState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

You are extending `Equatable` in `TodoState` and passing an empty list to `props`. When other states such as `TodoLoadedState` extend `TodoState` they inherit `Equatable` as well and the empty props.

> If you're using Equatable make sure to pass all properties to the
> props getter.

This is from bloc [faq](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=state-not-updating). Right now all instances of your `TodoLoadedState` are considered equal. Doesn't matter if you have a `TodoLoadedState` with hundreds of `loadedUser` or a `TodoLoadedState` with none. They are both considered equal and only the first time you pass a new `TodoLoadedState` the `BlocBuilder` will update. The consequent ones have no effect since `BlocBuilder` thinks it is the same as previous one. The reason your `LoadTodos` event causes a rebuild is that first you emit `TodoLoadingState()` and then in case of success `TodoLoadedState(loadedUser: _loadedTodoList)`. This alternating between two different states makes it work.

So either don't use `Equatable` or make sure to pass all the properties to `props`.

```
class TodoLoadedState extends TodoState {
  final List<dynamic> loadedUser;

  TodoLoadedState({required this.loadedUser});
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [loadedUser];
}
```

Comment: You helped me a lot. thanks a lot :)